# When L'Hopital's rule fails (again)

Tags: calculus, limits

I just realized that there may be a case where L'Hopital's rule fails, specifically

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x}$$

which evaluates to an indeterminate form, specifically $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Sure, we can cancel the $e^x$s, but when we use L'Hopital's, we get

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(e^x)^\prime}{(e^x)^\prime}$$

Since the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, we have

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x}$$

which is our original limit. Therefore, L'Hopital's fails to work in this example.

Question: Does L'Hopital's rule actually fail in this example, or am I understanding it wrong?

Edit: I mean "fails" in which it does not make progress toward a determinate result.

Comment: Why do you think it fails? obviously the limits are identical.

Comment: Fail in the sense of giving a false result?  No.  Fail in the sense of not making "progress" toward a determinate form? Yes.  You simply have:  $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x} $$

Comment: L'Hopital's rule tells you that, in this situation, if the limit obtained differentiating the numerator and the denominator exists, then so does the previous limit and they are both equal.

Comment: @Countable In the case where the ratio of derivatives by evaluation is still an indeterminate form, you apply it again.

Comment: @Countable The ratio is $1$.

Comment: Ah yeah I should have said this, it does work, he just used it incorrectly, yes obviously the limit is 1.

Comment: How did I use it incorrectly?

Comment: There isn't a notion of "you can apply it" or not, other than if the precise statement of the theorem holds (which obviously it does in this case), that is the point that I meant to make, the theorem is correct, you just have to read the precise statement of it.

Comment: L'Hopital doesn't fail, it just doesn't really tell you anything useful in this case.

Comment: The theorem states that if the limit of the ratio of the derivatives from the right exists (and the original limits are both + infinity from the right) then the original limit from the right has the same value. So the limit of ratios of derivatives in this case is 1 like saulspatz pointed out, so the L'Hospitals rule just tells you the original limit is also 1 (the same statements can be made about left hand limits and two sided limits) @new QOpenGLWidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, L'Hopital's Rule does not fail, in the usual sense of “fail”, only in the sense that you've added at the end of your question: you can apply it as many times as you wish without ever getting an answer.

And there are other cases:$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{-1}}{x^{-1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x^{-2}}{-x^{-2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^{-3}}{2x^{-3}}=\cdots$$

Comment: Nice example at the end. +1

Answer (score 5):

Just to add the precise statement to explain clearly what is going on:

$\textbf{Theorem - L'Hospital's Rule:}$ Let $a,b\in [-\infty,\infty]$. Suppose that f and g are differentiable real valued maps on $(a,b)$, with $g'(x)\neq 0$ on $(a,b)$., and the following hold:

(i) $\lim_{x\to b}f(x) = \lim_{x\to b}g(x) = +\infty$

and (ii) $\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L\in [-\infty,\infty]$,

then we can finally say that $\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L$.

Certainly $e^x$ is $C^{\infty}$, and  the conditions (i) and (ii) hold with $L = 1$, so our original limit is 1 also (not that we needed L'Hospital's rule for that, but there it is, it works here).

Answer (score 0):

L'Hôpital's Rule says that if $\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}}=L $, then $\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=L$. With $f'(x)=e^x$ and $ g'(x)=e^x$ is obviously true. L'Hôpital's Rule is also valid when $x\to \infty $.

Answer (score 0):

No. L'Hopital does not fail.

The L'Hopital rule says that (under some assumptions) if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=L$ then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L
$$

In your example,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^x}=1
$$

One should not blame L'Hopital if one does not know how to calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ when it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

The rule lets us write $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f}{g}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{hf}{hg}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{(hf)^\prime}{(hg)^\prime}$, so sometimes you need a non-constant $h$ to make progress.

With examples of the form $f/f$, we can take $h=x^k/f$, where the choice of $k$ is a context-dependent exercise.

More interesing is needing to transform. For example, consider $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x}$, which after $n$ iterations gives $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{n!x^{n+1}}$, not helpful at all. But $y:=\frac1x$ converts it to $\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y}{e^y}=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^y}=0$.

Since such a transformation changes the variable with respect to which we differentiate, by the chain rule it uses the more general $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f}{g}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{j(hf)^\prime}{j(hg)^\prime}$.